# strtotime with variable using php - object given

Tags: php

This is my current code:

```
$dateGame = new DateTime();
date_modify($dateGame, "+$universeTime Year");
$arrivalTime = date('Y-M-d H:i:s', strtotime("+$flightTimeMin minutes", $dateGame));
```

This isn't working because I believe "$dateGame" is an object. How would I turn it into something readable by "strtotime"?

Thanks

Comment: Why `strtotime()` if using `DateTime` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to use strtotime() since you are using datetime and you can use datetime object to format the date as

```
$universeTime = 3 ;
$flightTimeMin = 20;
$dateGame = new DateTime();
date_modify($dateGame, "+$universeTime Year +$flightTimeMin minutes");
```

If you want to format the display you can use as

```
echo $dateGame->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

or just use

```
echo $dateGame->date ;
```